# Arduino Uno DC Motor not working with simple test. Can not get Arduino to spin the motor

Tags: arduino

I am using the V2.3 motorsheild on the arduino uno r3.
I no almost nothing about ardunio excpet from what ive read about the past week.
I have been trying to simply turn the motor with the code below and it wont work. I have the arduino plugged into my computer and 12v going to the blue power box thing.
I am using this motor https://www.servocity.com/html/900_rpm_micro_gearmotorblocks.html#.VyELIFaDFBc
I cannot get the dang thing to spin, motor works fine if i wire it straight to the 5v/grnd but not when its in the M1 connection
wiring: https://i.groupme.com/747x1328.png.54a01e30433241d4a99905bd0e8ede2b let meknow if this link doesnt work
Heres an Imgur link for the wiring https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmiUP.jpg
    #include

```
AF_DCMotor motor(1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Motor test!");

  // turn on motor
  motor.setSpeed(200);

  motor.run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t i;

  Serial.print("tick");

  motor.run(FORWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }

  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }

  Serial.print("tock");

  motor.run(BACKWARD);
  for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }

  for (i=255; i!=0; i--) {
    motor.setSpeed(i);  
    delay(10);
 }


  Serial.print("tech");
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Did you try following adafruit tutorials, they usually explain it very very well :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in current particular shield and its library. But what i see when first time look at your sketch and motor connection image is that you are trying to run dc motor at a certain speed with commands, which seems to be for servo or stepper motors.

You should know that running DC motor at some speed is possible if you have speed calculation based on its current and voltage or when a speed sensor is located at motor's shaft. This motor doesn't have the sensor (i know it for sure, because used same in my projects) and i think the shield can't calculate speed. What you **can** is only switch it on and off and maybe change its direction.

So, first of all you should look (and use) at the library for such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for what the function you called "AF_DCMotor" does I see how you were confused. There is also [this product](https://learn.adafruit.com/afmotor-library-reference/af-dcmotor), which is another adafruit motor sheild.

But it's actually a very different motor driver. Both shields have a power stage which takes pulses and amplifies them to drive a motor. The V2 apparently has a chip which generates these pulses, and you send it serial data to command it using I2C. The V1 just gets these pulses directly from the Arduino.

For yours, a V2 motor shield, try the guide Adafruit provides.

[Here's the link - Adafruit Motor Sheild V2 DC motor control](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/using-dc-motors)

And here's the code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield(); 
Adafruit_DCMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getMotor(1);
AFMS.begin();
myMotor->setSpeed(100); 
myMotor->run(FORWARD);
```

It mentions the use of I2C on the introductory page

> Instead of using a latch and the Arduino's PWM pins, we have a fully-dedicated PWM driver chip onboard. This chip handles all the motor and speed controls over I2C

That's why it includes the Wire library. You could make your own code to run this, but it would have to use I2C to send commands to the PWM driver chip they are using.